# Is it possible to rename a docker container from inside the container itself?

Tags: docker

Hello I would like my containers to rename themselves. Is this possible?

I have an application running inside the containers which register themselves with an external platform, and when this happens they get a reference code, which I would like externalised to the docker process list on the host.

Comment: You can add a label or environment variable to each container when you run them. This label or variable can contain the reference code that the application inside the container receives from the external platform.

But this need to added either in the docker image compose file or in the docker run command while creating the docker

Comment: You could bind-mount the Docker socket into your container and then use the Docker API in principle.  But this would tightly connect your application to Docker, and having access to that socket makes it fairly easy to compromise the entire host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to my knowledge, at least for now, there is no way. Docker container is just an isolated OS process, which does not know that it is a container. AFAIK You can [rename containers from outside](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rename/) though.